# OpenGl 4.5 Shader doesn't loading

Tags: c++, opengl

I have written a code to show a point over a color screen, but I think that the shader is not working because I am changing the values of color and gl_Position, but the point in the screen doesn't change.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

GLuint compile_shaders();

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "That's an ERROR!" << std::endl;

    GLfloat color[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    float angle = 0.0;

    GLuint VAO;

    GLuint program = compile_shaders();
    std::cout << program << std::endl;
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        color[0] = (float)sin(angle)*0.5f + 0.5f;
        color[1] = (float)cos(angle)*0.5f + 0.5f;

        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);
        glUseProgram(program);
        glPointSize(40.0f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

        angle += 0.001f;

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

GLuint compile_shaders() {
    GLuint vertex_shader, fragment_shader, program;

    const GLchar* vertex_shader_source[] = {

        "#version 450 core                            \n"
        "                                             \n"
        "void main (void) {                           \n"
        "   gl_position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);   \n"
        "}                                            \n"
    };

    const GLchar* fragment_shader_source[] = {
        "#version 450 core                            \n"
        "out vec4 color;                              \n"
        "                                             \n"
        "void main() {                                \n"
        "   color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);         \n"
        "}                                            \n"
    };

    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);

    return program;
}
```

The code above, shows just a white square, that is the big pixel, over the animated screen. I've checked the functions with the return value, like glCreateProgram() and apparentely it's working fine.

What is wrong in the code?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you check if the shaders compile successfully? Do you get any shader compiler or linker errors? Do you get any OpenGL errors?

Comment: Ok, I will put the code in the text. How can I check this? Because some functions does not have a return value. I need to verify by a try-catch statement?

Comment: You are trying to set `gl_position` instead of `gl_Position`. I guess the shader compiler will complain about this. Have a look on this article on how to check for shader errors: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Shader_error_handling

Comment: Thank you very much man. You helped me a lot.